# How to implement a listener for a final method of an instance in Java

Tags: java, overriding, listener, final

I'm using a library where I want to implement a listener on one of the methods. My idea was to extend the class and override the method, but it appears I can't, because of the method being final (it appears to behave similarly for static methods).

**How can I implement a listener for a final method of an instance in Java?**

Here is an example demonstrating my problem:

```
public interface Listener {
    void somethingHappened();
}
```

---

```
public class Original {
    public final void override() {
        System.out.println("original");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Copy extends Original {
    private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    @Override
    public void override() { // offensive line: "Cannot override the final method from Original"
        System.out.println("copy");

        if (listener != null) {    
            for (Listener listener : listeners) {
                listener.somethingHappened();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am aware of not being able to override final methods (that's what the error message says). I am looking for alternatives.

Also, I want to avoid modifying the `Original` class if possible, since it is part of an external library, and forking it (given that this is possible) means maintaining it.

Comment: For everyone's information, in the end I found another viable class to extend and override methods for, eradicating the need for a listener pattern in the first place. But the question whether or not a listener can be implemented for a final method still stands.

Answer (score 2):

In Java the `final` method can't be overridden. The point of making a method final is to prevent it from being overridden.

For more details, go to [Writing Final Classes and Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).

Comment: "I am aware of not being able to override final methods (that's what the error message says). I am looking for alternatives?", not sure this is a useful answer?, can you add in some alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

A final method in Java has the intent of signalling that it can not be overridden. So  ideally you should not be trying to override it. Typically if you have had to do this you may want to rethink how to structure your code.

If you want to implement the listener it depends on whether you actually require `Copy` extending from `Original` (i.e. do you truly need to use it in place of `Original`) - if not then you could simply implement the interface on the `Copy` class or have a wrapper class which implements the interface.

Comment: The reason why I extend from `Original` is because I want to add a listener to its method (and because I don't want to dig into the source of the library which defines `Original`). What do you mean by "implement the interface on the `Copy` class"? I thought that was what I was doing (attempting).

Answer (score -2):

It depends on precisely what you are trying to do. However, you can add a listener as follows:

```
public class Copy extends Original implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void somethingHappened() {
        // Implement code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean this as an answer to my comment? You can edit it into your answer.